# How to get a user's worklist in windows workflow foundation 4.5

Tags: workflow-foundation, .net-4.5

We are building a multi-tenant application where there are changing workflows for approvals per office location set-up. We are considering windows workflow for managing the state. Our challenge is to list down the items for a user based on state of the document in the workflow. To elaborate more one office may have roles A -> B -> C in the approval flow. In other case it could be A -> B + D (Parallel approvals) -> C and in some cases it could be A -> B -> E -> C. Now we want to show worklist for roles B,C, D & E as A is the person who creates the work items. We do not want to track the state of the document in the database. We want to use the state in workflow to show the worklist to these users. All the users are in same location for a workflow model and they are online in same work hours and they do not use notifications (e-mails etc) for approval flows.

Can anyone suggest how can we retrieve this information?

The application technology stack is Web Application (ASP.Net MVC) as client, Windows Workflow & Workflow Services (Middleware) SQL Server & XML for persistence.

Comment: You need to query the list of running instances. This is a duplicate of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560387/listing-currently-running-workflows-in-net-4-0/